# TYPO3: How to overwrite bootstrap_package template?

Tags: typo3, bootstrap-5, typo3-extensions

How to override `bootstrap_package` templates with sitepackage's template in TYPO3? I tried this code in the my sitepackage `setup.typoscript`.

```
plugin.tx_bootstrap_package {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/
            1 = EXT:fileadmin/templates/ext/bootstrap_package/Templates/
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/
            1 = fileadmin/templates/ext/bootstrap_package/Partials/
        }
        layoutRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/
            1 = fileadmin/templates/ext/bootstrap_package/Layouts/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "overwride"? Is it overwrite or override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem could be identified by looking at the current TypoScript of a page.
Use the `Template`module in the backend, select a page and then use the TSOB (`TypoScript-Object-Browser`) (selection in the drop down at the top of the working area)

Here you can select some configurations:
`Constants`/`Setup`: setup is the working configuration, but `constants` may prepare some data for the `setup`.

My preferences:

```
[x] Display comments  
[x] Sort alphabetically  
Display Constants [Substituted constants in green  V]
```

You also may need to switch conditions for individual pages.

then you can see the active TypoScript. where you can find that there is no structure which you have set.

in the `Constants` you have the values:

```
plugin.bootstrap_package {
    view {
        templateRootPath = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/
        layoutRootPaths = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
}
```

these constants are used only in:

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            20 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Seo/
            21 = {$plugin.bootstrap_package.view.templateRootPath}Seo/
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            20 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Seo/
            21 = {$plugin.bootstrap_package.view.partialRootPath}Seo/
        }
        layoutRootPaths {
            20 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Seo/
            21 = {$plugin.bootstrap_package.view.layoutRootPath}Seo/
        }
    }
}
```

in the `Setup` these constants are used:

```
page {
  10 {
    templateRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
        1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
        1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
        1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
    }
  }
}
```

(as Julian already wrote.)
if you substitute these constants it may look like:

```
page {
  10 {
    templateRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
        1 = EXT:site_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
        1 = EXT:site_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
        1 = EXT:site_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
    }
  }
}
```

If you have more paths you can insert additional values which are inspected in top down order for a matching FLUID template.

---

there are additional template paths in the bootstrap package, but those are relevant for CEs (content elements) and use other constants:

```
lib.contentElement {
    templateRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/
        10 = {$plugin.bootstrap_package_contentelements.view.templateRootPath}
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/ContentElements/
        10 = {$plugin.bootstrap_package_contentelements.view.partialRootPath}
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/ContentElements/
        10 = {$plugin.bootstrap_package_contentelements.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set an additional (layout|template|partial)RootPath via constants:
[Configuration > TypoScript > page.fluidtemplate](https://docs.typo3.org/p/bk2k/bootstrap-package/13.0/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#page-fluidtemplate)

The Bootstrap Package is not a normal Extbase-plugin. Instead it configures TypoScript directly on a global level. So e.g. [`page = PAGE`](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript#L35) - or the paths for the `FLUIDTEMPLATE` ([line 103](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript#L103))

```
page {
  10 {
    templateRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
        1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
        1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
        1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
    }
  }
}
```